# Elasticsearch - Remove old source in GrayLog2

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, graylog2

Firstly I have to say im newbie at curl so Im asking here

I have some sources in GrayLog2:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkelZ.jpg

and want remove them all

Used curl to delete "12:00:02:" source

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/graylog2_*/message/_query' -d ' {"query_string" : { "default_field" : "host", "query" : "12:00:02:" } }'
```

but got failture

```
{"_indices":{"graylog2_0":{"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":0,"failed":1,"failures":[{"index":"graylog2_0","shard":0,"reason":"QueryParsingException[[graylog2_0] request does not support [query_string]]"}]}}}}
```

Anyone can help me with properly curl command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing the first `query` keyword. Change your query to this

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/graylog2_*/message/_query' -d ' {"query": {"query_string" : { "default_field" : "host", "query" : "12:00:02:" } } }'
                                                                         ^
                                                                         |
                                                                  this was missing
```

Also you can use this equivalent query

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/graylog2_*/message/_query?q=host:"12:00:02:"'
```

But if you want to delete them all you can also use this query

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/graylog2_*/message/_query?q=host:*'
```